# Is there a limit on how many commits can be displayed in Sourcetree Mac?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I have a repository with several branches and a lot of commits. In the history viewer of SourceTree Mac, when **displaying all branches, including remote branches**, there is a limit on how far back I can view the history. That is, I can scroll down in the list view up to a certain commit, but not further. The history extends much further.

This is also noticeable when selecting a branch from the remotes section. Usually, when selecting a branch, the history list view jumps to the according commit. If the branch points to an old commit to which I cannot scroll manually, the jump does not occur.

On SourceTree for Windows, both workflows work fine. It takes SourceTree a while to load all commits, but eventually you can scroll down or jump to very old commits.

I'm also sure that it is not related to the repository. I have viewed the same clone in both SourceTree for Mac and Windows. That's really physically the same clone, in a file system shared by Mac and Windows.

How can I view the complete history in SourceTree Mac? Is there a setting I have overlooked?

Version info:

- SourceTree Mac Version 2.3.1 (69), Mac OS X 10.11.5 (15F34)
- SourceTree Windows Version 1.9.6.1, Windows 8.1

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem any more with Source Mac 2.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, SourceTree pulls the logs as much far as git provides from the repo and displays the history/graph. For one of my repos, I can see the history until the very first commit back in 2012.

[SourceTree's display of very first commit in 2012.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5uBH.png)

May be, you can check on the command line if there is an issue fetching history of logs.

Comment: Yes, it's again behaving like this for me with Source Tree 2.3.2. Maybe it was a problem with Source Tree 2.3.1. Maybe it was a performance problem and I was not patient enough to wait for the complete history to be pulled. Thank you for your answer.